# how to get total min and max from 2 array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 Arrays:

```
var ids = new Array(1234,4113,1111,1111,1234,1234);
var datas = new Array(2,4,5,1,2,8);
```

I want to get total min. & max. values from **datas** array but it must be filtered, so same **id** can not be counted.

```
//example result: 
var min = 2 * 4 * 1;
//example result: 
var max = 8 * 4 * 2;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Resig (of jQuery) has suggested a great set of methods for this ([blog post](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/)):

```
Array.max = function( array ){
  return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};

Array.min = function( array ){
  return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
};
```

Comment: I am sorry but i know these methods already, its not what i am talkin about.

Comment: @Vural - can you clarify what you are after then? I thought the issue was acquiring the min and max.

Comment: sorry, I'm still totally confused.  Are you always multiplying the 3 lowest, and 3 highest values? if so, just sort the Array numerically and grab 0,1,2 (min) and n,n-1,n-2 (max)

Comment: does the `ids` array ever come into play? I don't see how it applies.